# Way to check if url/file exists and download it

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, curl, wget

Is there any proper way in bash to check if lets say - zip file exists and download it. 
If there is no file, just wait for it and download when it is available.
So e.g it checks url every x seconds, download file if available and exit, else wait for it to download. Something like:

```
if curl --head --silent --fail -X POST https://192.168.1.2/file/file.zip 2> /dev/null;
then
    wget https://192.168.1.2/file/file.zip
else
    sleep 60 && #check every x seconds and download when available"
fi
```

Thank you,

Comment: Apart from the dangling `&&` in the `sleep` command, what issues do you have with your code?

Comment: My code was not retrying in case file is unavailable.

Comment: Ah, ok, yes, because it's not in a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply rerun the command until it succeeds:

```
while ! wget https://192.168.1.2/file/file.zip; do
    sleep 60
done
```

Answer (score 2):

`wget` has native options for both checking and retrying, here are some of them you may find useful and combine them accordingly:

```
--spider
           When invoked with this option, Wget will behave as a Web spider, which means that it will not download the pages, just check that they are there.

-w seconds
       --wait=seconds
           Wait the specified number of seconds between the retrievals.  Use of this option is recommended, as it lightens the server load by making the requests less frequent.  Instead
           of in seconds, the time can be specified in minutes using the "m" suffix, in hours using "h" suffix, or in days using "d" suffix.

           Specifying a large value for this option is useful if the network or the destination host is down, so that Wget can wait long enough to reasonably expect the network error to
           be fixed before the retry.  The waiting interval specified by this function is influenced by "--random-wait", which see.
    enter code here

-t number
       --tries=number
           Set number of tries to number. Specify 0 or inf for infinite retrying.  The default is to retry 20 times, with the exception of fatal errors like "connection refused" or "not
           found" (404), which are not retried.
```

and there are more of those in `man wget`